# Apache alias - redirect loop

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I have a VirtualHost configured as below:

```
AliasMatch  /static /var/www/alpha101/media/static
```

When I tried to access anything from `www.mydomain.com/static/css/style.css`, it says "redirect loop".

Is there way way I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for AliasMatch: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch

AliasMatch is uses regex matching instead of simple prefix matching.

In your case, using Alias would be more appropriate:

```
Alias /static /var/www/alpha101/media/static
```